# how to get the contents of a div when it is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 divs that have an onClick event. Then I want that when that div is pressed it will take the contents of the div that was pressed and then store it in a variable. how to make? I've tried it several times, but all the contents of the existing div are all called.
this my code. please help me

```
function uid(){
    return Date.now().toString(12) + Math.random().toString(12).substr(2);
}
    function loadContent() {
        let $ = jQuery;
        let api = "b97618b9d94f7f1090189b207f83ce52";
        let title = $('#titless').val();
        var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + api + "&language=en-US&query=" + title + "&page=1&include_adult=false";
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                $('#atas').empty();
                $.each(data.results, function(i, item) {
                    $('#atas').append(
                        $('<div />', {
                            'class': 'col-md-2 my-2 mx-2 align-center',
                            'id': uid(),
                            'style': 'border: solid;',
                            'onclick' : 'loadGrab()',
                            'html': [
                                `<img class="card-img-top" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/${data.results[i].poster_path}">
                            <h3 class="title">${data.results[i].title}</h3>
                            <h1 class="ida">${data.results[i].id}</h1>
                            `
                            ]
                        })
                    );
                });
            });
    }
    function loadGrab() {
        let $ = jQuery;
        let api = "b97618b9d94f7f1090189b207f83ce52";
        let id = $('.ida').text();
        let url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + id + "?api_key="+ api +"&language=en-US";
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {                        
                $("#titleasd").text(res.title);
            })
        
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your method call to include id that way you will always have a right id of clicked div.

```js
function loadContent() {
  let $ = jQuery;
  let api = "b97618b9d94f7f1090189b207f83ce52";
  let title = $('#titless').val();
  var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + api + "&language=en-US&query=" + title + "&page=1&include_adult=false";
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      $('#atas').empty();
      $.each(data.results, function(i, item) {
        $('#atas').append(
          $('<div />', {
            'class': 'col-md-2 my-2 mx-2 align-center',
            'id': uid(),
            'style': 'border: solid;',
            'onclick': `loadGrab(${data.results[i].id})`,
            'html': [
              `<img class="card-img-top" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/${data.results[i].poster_path}">
                            <h3 class="title">${data.results[i].title}</h3>
                            <h1 class="ida">${data.results[i].id}</h1>
                            `
            ]
          })
        );
      });
    });
}

function loadGrab(id) {
  let $ = jQuery;
  let api = "b97618b9d94f7f1090189b207f83ce52";
  let url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + id + "?api_key=" + api + "&language=en-US";
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      $("#titleasd").text(res.title);
    })

}
```

Comment: Glad could help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should never share the api key.

The problem here is you are taking id using `$('.ida)` which takes all the text

```
<div class="so" style="background: green;">
  <h1 class="ida">1</h1>
</div>
<div class="so" style="background: blue;">
  <h1 class="ida">2</h1>
</div>
<div class="so" style="background: red;">
  <h1 class="ida">3</h1>
</div>
```

The output for `$('.ida').text()` is "123"

Alternative is to use a unique id for each element
or
write it like this

```
function loadGrab(){
    $('.so').on('click', function(){
    let b = $(this).find('h1');
    console.log(b.text());
  })
}
```

by giving the name to your `<div>` class. Using `$(this)`, whichever `<div>` is clicked will give you respective `<div>'s` data

Here's the fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/krb6u02y/